# Scala main class error

Tags: scala

My Program - HelloWorld.scala

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

`jar cvfe HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld HelloWorld*.class`

After jar file is created i tried to get the output from jar file

```
java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

but i got the error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Predef$
        at HelloWorld$.main(HelloWorld.scala:12)
        at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Predef$
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

Comment: you have to add all the scala jars to your classpath

Comment: can you be more specific please, new to scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add line

```
Class-Path: /home/dmitin/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.1‌​2.3/scala-library-2.‌​12.3.jar
```

(i.e. your location of scala-library) to `HelloWorld.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

Then

```
java -jar HelloWorld.jar Dmytro
```

produces

```
Hello, Dmytro!
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the scala runtime and libraries into the java classpath, you can certainly do that from commandline, but I suggest you to use more comfortable tools, see for example the tutorial at [www.scala-lang.org](https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started-sbt-track/getting-started-with-scala-and-sbt-on-the-command-line.html)